# How to render the same component repeatedly with the same prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that renders an Icon component many times.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  return(
    <IconStar/>
    <IconStar/>
    <IconStar/>
    <IconStar/>
  );
}
```

I'm looking for a way to make something like:

```
function MyComponent(props) {

  const IconStarWithProp = (<IconStar size="2rem"/>);

  return(
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
  );
}
```

How can I do such thing? Do I have to use a HOC or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not viable make a other component only for render with specific props

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  return Array(4).fill().map(() => <IconStar size="2rem"/> );
}
```

the 4 of the Array you can use a props to render number of that component

Answer (score 4):

`const IconStarWithProp = (<IconStar size="2rem"/>)` isn't a correct way to do this because `IconStarWithProp` is React element, not React component, it cannot be used as a `<IconStarWithProp/>` component, and reusing it as `{IconStarWithProp}` element may result in problems.

This is the case for wrapper component, it can be defined outside component function:

```
const IconStarWithProp = () => <IconStar size="2rem"/>;

function MyComponent(props) { 
  return <>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
  </>;
}
```

`MyComponent` can be shortened for multiple `IconStarWithProp`:

```
function MyComponent(props) { 
  return Array(4).fill().map(() => <IconStarWithProp/>)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function IconStarWithProp() {
  return <IconStar size="2rem" />;
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  return(
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
    <IconStarWithProp/>
  );
}
```

Comment: `function IconStarWithProp() = {` is not valid javascript

Comment: @etarhan Thanks for noticing that. Accepted your edit without the inline comment. 